# .HTACCESS 301 Redirect After Changing From Sub-Domain to Domain. Can anyone help?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So through an arrangement with another publisher we were hosted on a subdomain, such as:

subsite.mainsite.com

And their DNS simply pointed to our ip.  Now we are back on our own domain and they are still directing to our ip, but my question is can I catch referrals made from subsite.mainsite.com and send a 301 redirect to the requester and redirect them to the proper domain?

I tried this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

thinking it would catch all.  It probably says a lot about my lack of experience with redirects. :D.  In some cases it works, in others it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me -`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName old.something.tld
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.tld$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: I put that in the apache configuration, not a .htaccess

Comment: This doesn't work for me... but I might be misunderstanding. should it be laid out as.....  Servername example.domain.com  ... or literally have the .tld?

Comment: tld = top level domain - IE .com or .net or whatever. What I'm doing is defining the virtualhost for the old domain to simply forward all domains to the new one. The virtualhost for old domain does not even have a document root defined. The stackoverflow broke the line breaks, I'm not sure why.